# How do I find if a value exists in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

If I have a dictionary:

```
d = {0:'Fred', 1:'Fred', 2:'Zippy', 3:'Bob'}
```

how can I find out how many times `"Fred"` occurs in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
c=0
for i in d.values():
    if i=='Fred':
        c+=1
print(c)
```

Comment: Answering obvious duplicates is generally discouraged and can attract downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am new here and I will be careful about it from now on.